# Runnable Interface : Replace this lambda with a method reference. (sonar.java.source not set. Assuming 8 or greater.)

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
private void runAsyncImport() {
      Runnable task = () -> runImport(); 
      new Thread(task).start();
}
```

I am getting sonar issue for the above code, Replace this lambda with a method reference. (sonar.java.source not set. Assuming 8 or greater.)

How to fix it

Answer (score 4):

If your class has a non-static `runImport()` method,
then you can write like this:

```
Runnable task = this::runImport;
```

If the `runImport()` method is static, then instead of `this`, write the name of the class, for example if the name of the class is `MyClass`, then:

```
Runnable task = MyClass::runImport;
```