# SonarLint: Replace this lambda with a method reference

Tags: java, lambda, sonarlint, method-reference, sonarlint-eclipse

I have a collection that contains a list of errors. I wanted to group these by a key (UUID UserId). For this I have copied the code from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30202075/4045364

```
Collection<FilterError> filterErrors = new ArrayList<FilterError>();

// ... some filterErrors get added to the collection ...

return filterErrors.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.getUserId()));
```

Sonar Lint gives me the following error:

> Replace this lambda with a method reference. `->`

**What I have tried:**

Based on these question: [SONAR: Replace this lambda with a method reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507937/sonar-replace-this-lambda-with-a-method-reference) and [Runable Interface : Replace this lambda with a method reference. (sonar.java.source not set. Assuming 8 or greater.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612287/runable-interface-replace-this-lambda-with-a-method-reference-sonar-java-sou)

```
filterErrors.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::getUserId()));
```

Based on this question: [Replace this lambda with method reference 'Objects::nonNull'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238341/replace-this-lambda-with-method-reference-objectsnonnull)

```
filterErrors.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UUID::getUserId()));
```

Both give the error:

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Is there a way I can resolve this SonarLint issue?

Comment: Your method references are wrong. It should be `groupingBy(UUID::getRetailerId)` (if `w` is `UUID`).

Comment: Have you tried simply using `TYPEOFw::getUserId`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the class name of the object being targeted by the stream.
Example:

```
List<String> list = ...;
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toUpperCase));
```

so in your case:

```
FilterError::getUserId
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case previously it was like this -

```
whitelist0.stream().filter(whitelistEntry -> !whitelistEntry.isEmpty()).map(s -> WhitelistEntry.of(s)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

As I need to pass a value to the function, so I did the following to replace the lambda with method reference -

```
whitelist0.stream().filter(whitelistEntry -> !whitelistEntry.isEmpty()).map(WhitelistEntry :: of).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```